# TSQL: Creating a view with a computed column from two separate tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `TaxLots` that I created using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio.TaxLots
(
    Ticker varchar(22) NOT NULL,
    SecurityDescription varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Class varchar(15) NULL,
    Ccy varchar(5) NULL,
    LSPosition char(3) NULL,
    Date date NULL,
    Quantity int NULL,
    LocAvgCost decimal(8,3) NULL,
    LocTaxCostBasis int NULL,
    LocMktVal int NULL,
    BaseAvgCost decimal(8,3) NULL,
    BaseTaxCostBasis int NULL,
    BaseMktVal int NULL,
    BaseUNRL int NULL,
    DateCreated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT Cast(GetDate() as Date)
)
GO
```

Then I created a second table called `BusinessDates` that I created using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio.BusinessDates
(
    Date date NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

I populated both tables with all the pertinent data and I now want to create a view called `TaxLotsHistory` that has all the columns from the `Taxlots` table and an additional column called `ReportDate` that pulls the last business date from the `BusinessDates` table before `DateCreated`.

For example: if the `DateCreated` date is `2016-08-15`, the `ReportDate` should be `2016-08-12`. Logically,

```
ReportDate = Max(BusinessDate) 
where BusinessDate < DateCreated
```

but given `BusinessDate` and `DateCreated` are in two separate tables, I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax. I had something along the lines of this but it isn't working:

```
CREATE VIEW Portfolio.TaxLotsHistory
AS
    SELECT
        Ticker, SecurityDescription, Class, Ccy, LSPosition, Date, Quantity, 
        LocAvgCost, LocTaxCostBasis, LocMktVal, BaseAvgCost, BaseTaxCostBasis, 
        BaseMktVal, BaseUNRL, DateCreated,
        (SELECT MAX(BusinessDate) 
         FROM Portfolio.BusinessDates D As ReportDate 
         WHERE D.BusinessDate) < T.DateCreated
    FROM
        Portfolio.TaxLots T
```

I'm currently getting an

> Incorrect Syntax error near keyword 'AS'

but I'm sure there are other things wrong with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're defining **two aliases** for the table in the inner most `SELECT`: `FROM Portfolio.BusinessDates D As ReportDate` - either use just `D` for the alias, or use `AS ReportDate` - but not both .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE VIEW Portfolio.TaxLotsHistory
AS
Select  Ticker, SecurityDescription, Class, Ccy, LSPosition, Date, Quantity, 
LocAvgCost, LocTaxCostBasis, LocMktVal, BaseAvgCost, BaseTaxCostBasis, 
BaseMktVal, BaseUNRL, DateCreated,
( Select Max(D.BusinessDate) 
  From Portfolio.BusinessDates D
  Where D.BusinessDate) < T.DateCreated ) As ReportDate
From Portfolio.TaxLots T
```

Answer (score 1):

use Apply..

```
Create view vwname as
Select  Ticker, SecurityDescription, Class, Ccy, LSPosition, Date, Quantity, 
LocAvgCost, LocTaxCostBasis, LocMktVal, BaseAvgCost, BaseTaxCostBasis, 
BaseMktVal, BaseUNRL, DateCreated,b.reportdate
from
Portfolio.TaxLots t
cross apply
(
(Select Max (BusinessDate) As ReportDate  From Portfolio.BusinessDates D 
Where D.BusinessDate) < T.DateCreated
) b
```